# How to constain maxWidth of flutter Tooltip?

Tags: flutter, dart

if the tooltip message is very long, the tooltip expands on the full screen size. How to avoid it and fix max width of tooltip message or convert it to multiline text?

```
Tooltip(
   message: "A very, very, very, very loooooooooooooooooong text of information icon",
   child: Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with this and just tweak with margin

```
// call from outside 
 getToolTip("A very, very, very, very loooooooooooooooooong text of information icon", GlobalKey())

// tooltip        
getToolTip(String message, GlobalKey _toolTipKey) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: (){
      final dynamic _toolTip = _toolTipKey.currentState;
      _toolTip.ensureTooltipVisible();
    },
    child: Tooltip(
      key: _toolTipKey,
      waitDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      showDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      preferBelow: true,
      verticalOffset: 20,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 50), //here you change the margin 
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      height: 16,
      message: message,
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: This can yield unwanted results depending on the screen size especially when hardcoding the margin.

Comment: Is it possible to change the margin with the aspect ratio of screen using mediaQuery width, that's why I didn't write?

Comment: This answer seems more responsive for web apps. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You can use richMessage property instead of message.

```
                     Tooltip(
                            richMessage: WidgetSpan(
                                alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.baseline,
                                baseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  constraints:
                                      const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250),
                                  child: Text("Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Message"),
                                )),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0XFFDFE0FF),
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(4)),
                            ),
                            preferBelow: false,
                            verticalOffset: 10,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.info_outline,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This way really solves the problem, rather than a short fix.

Comment: I didn't know about WidgetSpan widget. Thanks, you made my day. I was dealing with multiple TextSpan elements without being able to really manage the visual layout. As this is like building a widget inside the tooltip, this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add a break-line (`\n`) within the message. So for instance:

```
Tooltip(
   message: "A very, very, very, very\nloooooooooooooooooong\ntext of information icon",
   child: Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded),
)
```

Comment: What if the text/data comes from an API?

Comment: Not a scalable solution.

Comment: @Prabhu AP 's solution below is the correct answer please follow that